# Insert MySQLi in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli, fullcalendar

I need help with FullCalendar and Javascript and PHP.
I need to include this foreach PHP code into this Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

events: [


    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM eventi";
    $eventi = $mysqli->query($sql);
    foreach ($users as $row) {
      echo '{';
      echo 'title: "'.$eventi['nome'] . '"';
      echo 'start: "'.$eventi['data'] . '"';
      echo '},';
    }
      ?>
]

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do not build your own json. Instead, build an array, then use json_encode. You can then echo it into your javascript, as long as the javascript does not need to interact with the PHP directly, and needs to run when the page loads.

Comment: @ChrysUgwu could you make an example?

Comment: See https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: You can do this by just renaming the file so it has a ```.php``` extension. The php code will be run when the page loads. I would also echo @aynber about build an array then echo the json_encode of the array.

Comment: @SloanThrasher it's already .php file.

Comment: Could you do an example?

Comment: Working on it, but if it's already a php file, what's wrong with the resulting page?

Comment: Javascript loads it as javascript code and not php.

Comment: What does the code say in that section, in the browser source?

Comment: No need to ALL CAPS your titles, it felt like you were yelling at me!

Comment: @d_kennetz, where do you see all caps? Are you sure you commented on the right question/thread?

Comment: *"Javascript loads it as javascript code and not php."* What do you mean by that? Look in your browser at the source of the rendered page. Maybe edit your question and show the first few lines of the data as rendered in the page source.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I edited his title, which was in all caps prior to edit.

Comment: @ChrysUgwu actually this code would work, assuming the code is within a PHP script. It's not very good practice, but it would work.

Comment: @RiccardoZunino "Javascript loads it as javascript code and not php." This makes no sense. Do you understand that PHP runs on the server, and JavaScript runs in the browser? The PHP will run first. The _output_ of that PHP then becomes a part of the final page delivered to the browser. You can use PHP to output HTML, CSS, JavaScript or just plain text. Whatever the final result is, it's used by the browser. Your example code above is crude, but it looks like it would work (assuming your date is in a valid format for fullCalendar to read).

Comment: @RiccardoZunino In this case, if you want to check what the PHP has created, then take a look at your finished JavaScript in the "View Source" source window of your browser, or via your browser's Developer Tools, and see if it contains what you expected. It's unclear specifically what your problem is. You've said "I need to do it" and then...you've done it. Is something not working as you wanted?  
 What is happening instead? Please be clear and specific about your issue.

Comment: @ADyson you are right, i misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2):

By changing your query so ite returns the data with the desired column names, and then using json_encode to format the results, you can 
simplify the code quite a bit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: [
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT `nome` as `title`, `data` as `start` FROM eventi";
            $eventi = $mysqli->query($sql);
            $allrows = $eventi->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $rslt = json_encode($allrows);
            echo $rslt;
        ?>
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all() in <b>/home/savona11/public_html/pannello/events.php</b> on line <b>68</b><br />

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: i'M USING 5.5.38

Comment: Ah, that's the issue. That version is past end of life. Can you upgrade PHP to a current version? If not, you should be able to change back to the loop you had before.